# Getting Context in a NUnit testing

Tags: c#, wcf, testing, nunit, moq

I have a WCF service that I am unit testing. I need to save OperationContext to use it in my testing. Context is not saved so can not use it to post back in my test. What is the best way I can save the current context to use it in my testing?

Comment: can you post the code you want to test?

Answer (score 1):

You can't normally mock OperationContext (unless you wrap it). But check this out , if it is help full for you.

http://blog.gfader.com/2010/08/how-to-unit-test-wcf-service.html

Some alternatives are :

1)  Another approach is simply refactoring your code. Take away all business logic from your service into separate testable business class and let the service participate only in integration test. Service is more like infrastructure and not everything really needs unit test. Integration / end-to-end / behavior test is also test and valid approach.

2) Use more poweful testing framework. Check [Moles framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798506.aspx) which is able to intercept calls and redirect them. This enables "mocking" sealed classes and static methods/properties. Using Moles you can redirect calls to OperationContext to your own methods.

Comment: Do you have some example where Moles is using Context to post back on dualchannel WCF Service or similar? Thanks

Comment: Sorry i don't have , i just read some articles and posted answer for you, i hope it helps you.

Comment: You mentioned in your answer unless I wrap it? what do you mean is there some example? thanks

Comment: Wrap access to OperationContext in custom class and inject an instance of the class to your service. This will involve additional work because you will need to do injection somewhere outside your service. For example constructor injection will need custom IInstanceProvider.

Comment: Go for alternative 1 and separate the business logic from the WCF behavior. You don't want to include dependencies to WCF in your test, you want to mock them out.